# Blazor componen css is not loading when component is in folder

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassembly app. When I create a `*.razor.css` file for the component in one of the two default folders (Pages, Shared) everything works just fine. But I want to organize my code into subfolders like `Pages/Components`. I have created a new folder and test component in it `Pages/Components/Test.razor`. I have also added `@using Project.Pages.Components` to `_Imports.razor`. When I use the test component in my app it loads correctly. But I have an issue with CSS. I have created the CSS file `Pages/Components/Test.razor.css`. It looks like this file is ignored. When I look into `Project.styles.css` file which contains processed CSS of components from those two default folders it does not contains any CSS rules from the test file.

Is it possible to somehow configure blazor to include CSS from subfolders?

Comment: Tried to test your scenario and it seems to load the styles correctly. Maybe you need to clear browser cache?

Comment: Two suggestions to the one above.  1. Clear and rebuild the code. 2. <Ctl>F5 the application when running.